# R after median imputation nothing changes

Tags: r, imputation

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on here? I'm trying to do imputation on NA values but I'm getting nowhere. Here is my dataframe. I'm including the whole thing only because I thought maybe it would be helpful to have the full thing instead of just the first n rows:

```
structure(list(INDEX = 1:6, TARGET_WINS = c(39L, 70L, 86L, 70L, 
82L, 75L), TEAM_BATTING_H = c(1445L, 1339L, 1377L, 1387L, 1297L, 
1279L), TEAM_BATTING_2B = c(194L, 219L, 232L, 209L, 186L, 200L
), TEAM_BATTING_3B = c(39L, 22L, 35L, 38L, 27L, 36L), TEAM_BATTING_HR = c(13L, 
190L, 137L, 96L, 102L, 92L), TEAM_BATTING_BB = c(143L, 685L, 
602L, 451L, 472L, 443L), TEAM_BATTING_SO = c(842, 1075, 917, 
922, 920, 973), TEAM_BASERUN_SB = c(NA, 37L, 46L, 43L, 49L, 107L
), TEAM_BASERUN_CS = c(NA, 28L, 27L, 30L, 39L, 59L), TEAM_BATTING_HBP = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), TEAM_PITCHING_H = c(9364L, 1347L, 1377L, 1396L, 1297L, 1279L
), TEAM_PITCHING_HR = c(84L, 191L, 137L, 97L, 102L, 92L), TEAM_PITCHING_BB = c(927L, 
689L, 602L, 454L, 472L, 443L), TEAM_PITCHING_SO = c(5456L, 1082L, 
917L, 928L, 920L, 973L), TEAM_FIELDING_E = c(1011L, 193L, 175L, 
164L, 138L, 123L), TEAM_FIELDING_DP = c(NA, 155L, 153L, 156L, 
168L, 149L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I look to see if there are any NA values

```
any(is.na(moneyball_training_data)) # TRUE
```

I find where these NA values are:

```
moneyball_training_data %>% summarise(across(, ~ any(is.na(.x))))
```

I look at the class of one of the variables that has NA values

```
class(moneyball_training_data$TEAM_BATTING_SO) # numeric
```

I try to impute it with the median value of that vector:

```
moneyball_training_data$TEAM_BATTING_SO[moneyball_training_data$TEAM_BATTING_SO == NA] <- median(moneyball_training_data$TEAM_BATTING_SO)

any(is.na(moneyball_training_data$TEAM_BATTING_SO)) # TRUE
```

But I still get TRUE when I ask if there are NA values...

But maybe I forgot to remove NA in the function call for medican so I try again with an na.rm = TRUE

```
moneyball_training_data$TEAM_BATTING_SO[moneyball_training_data$TEAM_BATTING_SO == NA] <- median(moneyball_training_data$TEAM_BATTING_SO, na.rm = TRUE)

any(is.na(moneyball_training_data$TEAM_BATTING_SO)) # TRUE
```

But that doesn't work. So I find the median value another way and then use that value for the imputation:

```
median(moneyball_training_data$TEAM_BATTING_SO, na.rm = TRUE) # 750

moneyball_training_data$TEAM_BATTING_SO[moneyball_training_data$TEAM_BATTING_SO == NA] <- 750

any(is.na(moneyball_training_data$TEAM_BATTING_SO)) # TRUE
```

But this doesn't impute 750 for the NA values. But maybe I should just use "" instead of NA:

```
moneyball_training_data$TEAM_BATTING_SO[moneyball_training_data$TEAM_BATTING_SO == ""] <- 750

any(is.na(moneyball_training_data$TEAM_BATTING_SO)) # TRUE
```

But this doesn't work either. Anyone know why isn't this imputation working?

Comment: Try using `is.na()` instead of  `== NA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the `boolean` vector for subsetting you should use `is.na()` which you already correctly used before and afterwards.

```
moneyball_training_data$TEAM_BATTING_SO[is.na(moneyball_training_data$TEAM_BATTING_SO)] <- median(moneyball_training_data$TEAM_BATTING_SO, na.rm = TRUE)

any(is.na(moneyball_training_data$TEAM_BATTING_SO)) #
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks for this answer. I didn't think to put the is.na in the vector as you suggest. Any specific why is.na works and == NA or == "" doesn't work?

Comment: `== ""` does not work simply because the missing value in your `data.frame()` are coded `NA` and not `""`.  As to why `== NA` does not work is a bit more tricky to answer. The `R` documentation for `?"=="` yields that missing values for `NA` are regarded as non-comparable.